# Showing that there exists $S\in A:|\mu(C\Delta S)|<\epsilon$ and $|\mu(C)-\mu(S)| < \epsilon$ if $A$ is an algebra generating the sigma algebra $F$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X, F, \mu)$ be a probability space, $A$ an algebra generating $F$, $C\in F$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. My probability theory material claims (without a proof) that

> As $A$ generates $F$ there exists $S \in A$ s.t. $\mu(C\Delta S) < \epsilon$. Hence $|\mu(C) - \mu(S)| < \epsilon$.

Intuitively this claim makes sense: An algebra is essentially a finite version of a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore we can approximate, w.r.t. a measure $\mu$, to an arbitrary precision any element of $F$ with elements of $A$. But then the question becomes how one can actually show this without hand-waving.

Comment: Theorem D p, 56 of Measure Theory by Halmos. This question has appeared many times on this site.

Comment: @geetha290krm Roger that and thanks for the reference! I tried to search this question before posting it but by either different wording (or just bad luck) I couldn't find an answer which helped me.

Comment: @geetha290krm Now that I took a closer look at Halmos' book, I have to say that I am still a bit unsure how you would argue about $\left|\mu(C) - \mu(S)\right| < \epsilon$ given the $S$ s.t. $\mu(C\Delta S) < \epsilon$.

Comment: $|\mu(C)-\mu (S)| =|[\mu(C\cap S)+\mu(C\setminus S)]-[\mu (S\cap C)+\mu(S\setminus C)|\leq \mu(C\setminus S)+\mu(S\setminus C)=\mu (C\Delta S)$.